# Clickable NSButtonCell in NSTextFieldCell in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

[image]
I subclassed a NSTextFieldCell that called MyTextFieldCell.
I add a NSButtonCell in it.

Does anyone know, How to let NSButttonCell clickable in MytextFieldCell?

Code:

```
class MyTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

    var checkButtonCell: NSButtonCell

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        let cell = NSButtonCell()
        cell.bezelStyle = .ThickerSquareBezelStyle
        cell.setButtonType(.SwitchButton)
        cell.title = nil
        self.checkButtonCell = cell

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawWithFrame(cellFrame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView) {

        var checkRect = NSRect()
        var textRect = NSRect()
        NSDivideRect(cellFrame, &checkRect, &textRect, 21.0, NSRectEdge.MaxX)

        super.drawWithFrame(cellFrame, inView: controlView)
        self.checkButtonCell.drawWithFrame(checkRect, inView: controlView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a modern view based table view. It makes things so much easier.

Comment: Does the NSButtonCell have a target and an action?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a button in a cell, I reccommend doing

`selectionStyle = .None`

inside of `awakeFromNib()`of the Cell's class to start with in order to prevent the cell from thinking you are clicking it when the user is trying to click the button like so...

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    selectionStyle = .None
}
```

Create the outlets to your button in the Button class. The easiest way to deal with the action to the button is just create it inside of the ViewController class instead of the cell. It is possible to create it inside the cell and use a delegate to communicate with the viewController, but the easiest method would be to create the @IBAction in the ViewController itself. Creating it there is completely aloud although the @IBOutlet has to be in the Cell's Class. Then if you need to change the button in some way, change it inside of the table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and call

`tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(NSIndexPath(forRow: theCellRow, inSection: theCellSection), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)`

at the point that you want to see the change happen and the changes were previously made. I hope this helps! ;)

Comment: Thanks Sethmr, But it is not for NSTableView

Comment: oh, my bad... the same principle still applies. Keep the outlets local to your defining class and the actions in the view controller corresponding the the cell.